# Hibernate 5 @joinformula with @MapKeyTemporal

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I can't do select last using joinformula. The maps works fine but using the join formula the folow error was showed:

A Foreign key InstrumentoData from Instrumento has the wrong number of column. should be 2

```
@MapKeyTemporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@MapKey(name = "dataMovimento")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "instrumento")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
private final Map<Date, InstrumentoData> instrumentoData = new HashMap<>();

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinFormula(value = "(SELECT i.ID_INSTRUMENTO FROM InstrumentoData i WHERE i.ID_INSTRUMENTO = id ORDER BY i.data_Movimento DESC LIMIT 1)")
private InstrumentoData ultimoInstrumentoData;
```

any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "ID_INSTRUMENTO")),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "(SELECT i.data_Movimento FROM  Instrumento_Data i WHERE i.ID_INSTRUMENTO = id ORDER BY i.data_Movimento FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY)", referencedColumnName = "data_Movimento"))
})
private InstrumentoData ultimoInstrumentoData;
```